# Write a function, called filter_out(), which takes a list of integers as input and return the list filtered by only keeping numbers

Tags: python

Write a function, called filter_out(), which takes a list of integers as input and return the list filtered by only keeping numbers that are multiples of 5, or 7 but not both, e.g., list = [5, 7, 35, 49] returns [5, 7, 49].

My problem is I cannot remove the number which both are multiples of 5 and 7.

```
def filter_out(my_list):
    a_list = []
    for number in my_list:
        if number % 5 == 0 or number % 7 == 0:
            a_list.append(number)
    return a_list

print(filter_out([1, 2, 3, 5]))
[5]
print(filter_out([5, 7, 35, 49]))
[5, 7, 49]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if number can't be divided by 35.

```
if (number % 5 == 0 or number % 7 == 0) and number % 35 != 0:
        a_list.append(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a condition that checks for that:

```
def filter_out(my_list):
    a_list = []
    for number in my_list:
        if (number % 5 == 0 or number % 7 == 0) and number % 35 != 0:
            a_list.append(number)
    return a_list
```

I checked division by 35 because that is 5*7 of course

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You could use the following function to vectorize the list using `numpy` and then

1. evaluate `mod(list_array, 5)` and `mod(list_array, 7)`.
2. `drop` = find intersection of values in list_array that came out to be zero in previous step.
3. `keep` = all values - values from step-2 (*this is what you want*).

The final implementation is a single line function call as shown below.

```py
# call function to get list of numbers to keep and to drop
keep, drop = process_to_keep(list_of_values, n=5, m=7)
```

> ### Code with Example and Output

```py
import numpy as np

# dummy data
l = [5, 7, 35, 49]

# function to process data
def process_to_keep(list_of_values, n=5, m=7):
    a = np.array(list_of_values)
    A = a%n
    B = a%m
    drop = set(a[A==0]).intersection(set(a[B==0]))
    keep = set(a) - drop
    return list(sorted(keep)), list(sorted(drop))

# call function to get list of numbers to keep and to drop
keep, drop = process_to_keep(l, n=5, m=7)
print(' keep: {}\n drop: {}'.format(keep, drop))
```

**Output**:

```
 keep: [49, 5, 7]
 drop: [35]
```

> ### Another Example

The function is generic. And so we can test it against another list: `[5,7,30,35,42,49,50,70,100,105]`.

```py
keep, drop = process_to_keep([5,7,30,35,42,49,50,70,100,105], n=5, m=7)
print(' keep: {}\n drop: {}'.format(keep, drop))
```

**Output**:

```
 keep: [5, 7, 30, 42, 49, 50, 100]
 drop: [35, 70, 105]
```

> ### One More Example

Assume you want to check if a list of numbers are individually divisible by 10 or 7, but not by both. The same function takes care of this as well.

```py
keep, drop = process_to_keep([5,7,30,35,42,49,50,70,100,105], n=10, m=7)
print(' keep: {}\n drop: {}'.format(keep, drop))
```

**Output**:

```
 keep: [5, 7, 30, 35, 42, 49, 50, 100, 105]
 drop: [70]
```